# Detecting Collision between two filled Rectangles

Tags: java, collision-detection, game-physics

I'm trying to make it print out "Game over" when the Green Square(**Cuboid**) runs over/into the blue(**CuboidKiller**) one.

**GAME class:**

```
package plugin.dev.wristz;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 294623570092988970L;

    public static ArrayList<CuboidKiller> killers;

    public static int h = 1024, w = 768;

    public static Game game;
    public static Graphics graphics, g2;
    public static Image image;

    public static Cuboid cuboid;

    public Game(String title) {
        setTitle(title);
        setSize(1024, 768);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        addKeyListener(new KeyHandler(cuboid));

        g2 = getGraphics();
        paint(g2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cuboid = new Cuboid();
        Thread cubi = new Thread(cuboid);
        cubi.start();

        killers = new ArrayList<CuboidKiller>();

        CuboidKiller a = new CuboidKiller(new Random().nextInt(h), new Random().nextInt(w), new Random().nextInt(50) + 20);

        killers.add(a);

        game = new Game("Killer Cuboids");
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        image = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        graphics = image.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(graphics);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        checkGameOver();

        cuboid.draw(g);

        for (CuboidKiller killer : killers)
            killer.draw(g);

        repaint();
    }

    public void checkGameOver() {
        for (CuboidKiller killer : killers)
            if (killer.isTouching(cuboid))
                System.out.println("Game over!");

    }

    public int getH() {
        return h;
    }

    public void setH(int wh) {
        h = wh;
    }

    public int getW() {
        return w;
    }

    public void setW(int ww) {
        w = ww;
    }

}
```

**Cuboid class:**

```
package plugin.dev.wristz;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public class Cuboid implements Runnable {

    private int x, y, xDirection, zDirection;

    public Cuboid() {
        this.x = 799;
        this.y = 755;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        g.fillRect(x, y, 25, 25);
    }

    public void move() {

        x += xDirection;
        y += zDirection;

        if (x <= 10)
            x = 0 + 10;

        if (y <= 35)
            y = 0 + 35;

        if (x >= 1024 - 35)
            x = 1024 - 35;

        if (y >= 768 - 35)
            y = 768 - 35;

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ev) {
        int keyCode = ev.getKeyCode();

        if (keyCode == ev.VK_LEFT) {
            setXDirection(-5);
        }

        if (keyCode == ev.VK_RIGHT) {
            setXDirection(5);
        }

        if (keyCode == ev.VK_UP) {
            setZDirection(-5);
        }

        if (keyCode == ev.VK_DOWN) {
            setZDirection(5);
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ev) {
        int keyCode = ev.getKeyCode();

        if (keyCode == ev.VK_LEFT) {
            setXDirection(0);
        }

        if (keyCode == ev.VK_RIGHT) {
            setXDirection(0);
        }

        if (keyCode == ev.VK_UP) {
            setZDirection(0);
        }

        if (keyCode == ev.VK_DOWN) {
            setZDirection(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                move();
                Thread.sleep(5);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getXDirection() {
        return xDirection;
    }

    public void setXDirection(int xDirection) {
        this.xDirection = xDirection;
    }

    public int getZ() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setZ(int z) {
        this.y = z;
    }

    public int getZDirection() {
        return zDirection;
    }

    public void setZDirection(int zDirection) {
        this.zDirection = zDirection;
    }

}
```

**Cuboid Killer:**

```
package plugin.dev.wristz;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CuboidKiller {

    private int x, y, radius;

    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> points;

    public CuboidKiller(int x, int y, int radius) {
        this.points = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        setPoints();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.blue);

        g.fillRect(x, y, radius, radius);
    }

    public void setPoints() {
        this.points.put(x, y);
        this.points.put(x + radius, y);
        this.points.put(x + radius, y - radius);
        this.points.put(x, y - radius);
    }

    public boolean isTouching(Cuboid cuboid) {
        boolean result = true;

        //int a = cuboid.getX(), b = cuboid.getZ();

        result = true;

        return result;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public HashMap<Integer, Integer> getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(HashMap<Integer, Integer> points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [mcve]. I have the impression that you could shrink your quotes a little to focus on the actual rectangle question. E.g. reduce to a program calling a function with the basic attribtues of the two rectanlges, expexting boolean return value. And maybe you can familiarise better with the formatting options offered by StackOverflow, to improve readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two approaches. Either you write it yourself, or you just use what Java 8 provides.

This guy has a very nice explanation on how to detect collision between two rectangles: [Java check if two rectangles overlap at any point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302698/java-check-if-two-rectangles-overlap-at-any-point/32088787#32088787)

But if I were the one writing it, I would just have both classes contain a `Rectangle` object (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html), and just call the `intersects()` function provided by `Rectangle`. :-)

Comment: I will try this tomorrow. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help :)