# JAVA - size of a portion created by overlapping rectangles

Tags: java, android

I looked at this post ([Java check if two rectangles overlap at any point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302698/java-check-if-two-rectangles-overlap-at-any-point)) to check the overlap of two rectangles. [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIe0S.png)

Now i need to know the size of red rectangle. How can i do it?

I reformulate the question as seen in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDXec.png), I need to know the size of each red sub-rectangle
Thank you in advance. 
Pasquale

Comment: Can you share with us what have you tried?

Comment: Try scribble it on paper. min & max & x2 (= x + width) might help abstract things

Comment: Use [`intersection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersection-java.awt.Rectangle-). Then multiply the `width` by the `height`.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the furthest-left side of the right-most rectangle from the furthest-right side of the left-most rectangle to get the width.

You can get the height using a similar technique with the Y axis.