# Find whether two rectangles overlap

Tags: algorithm, math, rectangles, overlapping

I am trying to find whether two rectangles overlap each other or not. I have the following rectangles represented as `[x1,x2] x [y1,y2]`

```
Rect 1 = [0.0, 1.0] x [0.0, 1.0]
Rect 2 = [0.7, 1.2] x [0.9, 1.5]
```

I just need a pseudo code that I can implement to find the whether rectangles overlap each other or not.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-two-rectangles-overlap/

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302698/java-check-if-two-rectangles-overlap-at-any-point/23302818 answers this.

Comment: @sasmith provided answer worked perfectly. Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ((Rect1.topLeft.x  >  Rect2.bottomRight.x) || (Rect1.bottomRight.x  <  Rect2.topLeft.x)  || (Rect1.topLeft.y > Rect2.bottomRight.y) || (   Rect1.bottomRight.y  <  Rect2.topLeft.y)):
            Then NOT OVERLAPPING
  else:
            OVERLAPPING
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If your rectangle represented as `[x1,x2] x [y1,y2]`:

```cpp
if (a.x1 > b.x2 || b.x1 > a.x2) return false; // check x-axis
if (a.y1 > b.y2 || b.y1 > a.y2) return false; // check y-axis
return true;
```

Condition `a.x1 > b.x2` checks if the left border of `a` lies to the right of the right border of `b`, if that is true then rectangles don't overlap. Other three conditions are similar.